# Laravel Inertia Vite

Tags: php, laravel, vite, inertiajs

In production mode (on the server), there is an error on my site in the Chrome console:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Page not found: ./Pages/Posts/Show.vue`

Also, the Dashboard page isn't updating to changes with text and a new pagination table I've introduced in local development.

Everything works fine locally, but pushing to Digital Ocean Server doesn't show the latest changes.

I checked the source code online and they raw code is there. I can see the changes in text, the pagination table and the new routes. But they are not showing when I load the website. I suspect something to do with the cache or the build process?

I have done:

`php artisan cache:clear`

`php artisan config:clear`

`php artisan view:clear`

`npm run build` (new vite build of assets)

Can anyone help?

Shared Files:

resources/js/app.js

```
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .mount(el);
    },
});

InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#4B5563' });
```

Post Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Post;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use App\Models\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display all posts
     *
     * @return \Inertia\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $posts = Post::paginate(10);
        
        return Inertia::render('Dashboard', ['posts' => $posts]);
    }


    /**
     * Display a post
     *
     * @return \Inertia\Response
     */
    public function show(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

        return Inertia::render('Posts/Show', ['post' => $post]);
    }    
}
```

Comment: can u confirm if the component `Pages/Posts/Show.vue` exists?

Comment: 100% exists - resources/js/Pages/Posts/Show.vue . Checked locally and production.

Comment: can u share your `resources/js/app.js` file? (edit the question)

Comment: Hi ericmp, updated as requested.

Comment: all seems good, not sure what is happening here, but the error makes me think the page is not found xD. maybe u created it in a wrong route?

Comment: If I do a dd($post) in the show method in the controller it shows the model correctly. The route is working... Super frustrating.

Comment: i meant the file path. if in a terminal u do `cat resources/js/Pages/Posts/Show.vue`, u see the file contents?

Comment: Yeah, I can see the file contents in production with that command.

Comment: and `npm run build` worked fine? this is really weird

Comment: I can see the Show page being built in the build output: "public/build/assets/Show.e7e38607.js                2.65 KiB / gzip: 1.08 KiB"

Comment: It also shows in the manifest.json

Comment: and if u try it in another browser or in incognito mode, u get the same? refresh browser cache maybe

Comment: I've tried safari, chrome, incognito, and my phone. Also cleared the browser caches.

Answer (score 0):

This was an docker/nginx issue. The files generated by the app weren't routing correctly and so the static files from the original build weren't being replaced.

I changed to using volumes to sync data between the containers and it worked.